# No option to choose between renewed and old(going to be expired) ios distribution certificate(adhoc) in xamarin as both have the same name

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have account of ios enterprise developers program . The iOS distribution(adhoc) certificate is supposed to  expire within a month . I have renewed the certificate. Now **in my account I have two iOS distribution certificate with the same name but different expiry dates.** In provisioning profile I can see two options for certificates(new and old), I renewed my provisioning profile with new certificate .But in  Xcode preferences-> accounts I can see only one certificate. Now ,in Xcode the certificate(expires july 2019) contains new provisioning profile(expires 2020). I tried to build the application in Xamarin using the above , the application crashes . **How can  I choose to build the application with the new certificate without revoking the old one(yet to expire).**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543709/how-setup-different-certificates-and-provisioning-profile-for-production-and-dev

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How setup different certificates and provisioning profile for production and development environment iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543709/how-setup-different-certificates-and-provisioning-profile-for-production-and-dev)